# Two Element Lists with Table Extension

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to use the table extension for my model. My code includes the **table:from-list** command to generate the table. However I am getting an error saying **"Extension exception: expected a two-element list". I generate the list from a txt file that is two columns of numerical data. Apparently this is not the correct format to create a two-element list, but I can't find any documentation describing the appropriate format. How can a two-element list be generated?

Also, is it possible to build a table with more than two elements? Time is serving as the **key** in my table, but I would like to build a table such that this key would update three different variables (hence a four column table: **ticks variable1 variable2 variable3**)

Any good resources for learning my way around the tables and arrays extensions is also welcomed (I've already checked out the extensions guide but don't have the hang of it yet).

```
extensions [table]

Globals
[ 
list-O2
table-O2           
]

to setup
make-lsolutes                            ; loads lists for solute data (based on node 96)
make-tsolutes                              

to go

if table:has-key? table-O2 ticks
[ update-from-FEM]

tick

end

to make-lsolutes

ifelse ( file-exists? "96O214day.txt" )                                                                
[
set list-O2 []
file-open "96O214day.txt"
while [ not file-at-end? ] [set list-O2 lput file-read list-O2]
file-close
]
[ user-message "There is no 96O214day.txt file in current directory!" ]

end

to make-tsolutes
set table-O2 table:from-list list-O2
end

to update-from-FEM
ask insulation 
[ set O2 table:get table-O2 ticks]
end
```

The txt files to make the solute lists have two columns. Left column is time, and the right column is O2 concentration. Columns are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-element list would look like this:

`[[key1 val1][key2 val2][keyn valn]]`

I would use the `file-open`, `file-read-line`, and `while [not file-at-end?]` primitives to iterate over your input and use the [String primitives](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#stringgroup) to create the pair-lists from your input file. Something like:

```
let the-list []
file-open filename.txt
while [not file-at-end?][
let input file-read-line
;; find the start and end position/index of key and value (X,Y,O,P) using the position primitive on your delimiter
let key substring input X Y
let value substring input O P
let the-pair (list key value)
set the-list lput the-pair the-list
]
```

You can embed tables inside tables. So if you want several values as key value, just create a table for each entry and put them in your main table.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I've been using your suggested method. Unfortunately due to the size of data I am using now, it is becoming time consuming to build the lists and then tables. Would you have any ideas for a method to create a table that can be read directly from an excel spreadsheet, without going through the time to build the table explicitly? My tables are increasing to include one list of **keys** and nearly a hundred **values** for different variables that must be updated when the key is called.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing that. Is the problem that you have to run this code every time you run your model? If so, you could skip this by writing the table to a file. If you first convert the table to a list using table:to-list, and then use file-write to write it to a file, you can use file-read and table:from-list to convert it back again. I haven't tested it, but I can't imagine it won't save you *some* time. I don't now how much, though.

Comment: @user3887089: suggest you open a new question on it

Comment: Thank you again for your help. The problem is that this table is changed frequently since the input to my model is changing. So just writing the table to a file I don't think is going to help, because it is constructing the table in a format that NetLogo can read it that takes a long time. Instead the large data set is instantly produced in  excel, hence the ideal solution is to find a method to create a NetLogo table that can read the excel file in its native format. I will open this up for a new question as suggested by Seth. Cheers.